# Convergence of compact sets continuous function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, convergence-divergence, continuity, compactness

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact set (both subset of the real number). Consider the continuous function $f:X \rightarrow Y$. For any given $y$, and for $h>0$ small enough so that $y+h \in Y$. I want to know whether it is true that 
$f^{-1}([y,y+h]) \rightarrow f^{-1}(y)$ when $h \rightarrow 0$

I know that $f^{-1}([y,y+h])$ is a closed set for each $h$.
My main problem is that we are talking about convergence between two sets. How do you define convergence between two sets?
More informally, my question is does the sequence of set converges to the set composed of the inverse of image of $f(y)$

help?

Answer (score 1):

We can talk about converge of a sequence of sets via the $\lim\inf$ and $\lim\sup$ of $(A_n)_n$ (*limit inferior* and *limit superior*, See [Definition of limit of a sequence of sets](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462905/definition-of-limit-of-a-sequence-of-sets/462923#462923)). They always exist, and if they are equal, then we define $$\lim A_n=\lim\inf A_n=\lim\sup A_n$$
For a monotone sequence of sets they always coincide, and the limit is just the intersection of all $A_n$ if the sequence is decreasing, or the union if it is increasing.

So $f^{-1}([y,y+h])\to f^{-1}(y)$ can be interpreted as $$\lim f^{-1}([y,y+h_n])=f^{-1}(y)\text{ for each sequence }h_n\to 0$$ However, if $h_n$ is not monotonically decreasing, then neither is $A_n:=f^{-1}([y,y+h_n])$. But it satisfies a weak form a monotonicity
$$\text{for all $n$ there is an $m$ such that $A_k⊆A_n$ whenever $k>m$}$$
For such a sequence the $\lim$ is still defined and equals the intersection of all sets. So you just have to show that $\bigcap_n f^{-1}([y,y+h_n])=f^{-1}(y)$